# Surrounding all text in PHP with double quotes isn't resulting in expected behavior, and is adding too many quotes

Tags: php, csv

I need to create a csv in which every field is surrounded by double quotes, including empty fields.

When I try this `$tempData[12] = '""';` Sublime text shows those cells with 6 sets of double quotes. When I leave it empty `$tempData[12] = '';`, sublime text shows them as having nothing.

Same with fields that actually have text. When I do this `$tempData[15] = '"General"';` my result is """General""", and when I do this `$tempData[15] = 'General';` my result is no double quotes at all (expected behavior).

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use PHP's [fputcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) instead of manually building it to begin with? With that function, you can configure it like you want it. Doing it manually requires you to also handle escaping (if a value contains the character `"` for example, you don't want things to break). It's more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: I initially run through an existing csv with my data and build an array of arrays out of it, then run through that array and use fputcsv on every row of the php array.
I do it that way, because sometimes I have to add data to an existing cell instead of creating a new one

Comment: Can you show more code of what you are actually doing and some example data? Its hard to understand so far. Also, are you sure sublime is not tricking you (showing more quotes than there actually are)?